# Finding longest prefix present on at least 2 elements on a list of "random" strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, prefix

Given a list of strings, for example:

```
myList = ["foo", "foobar", "football", "footbag", "bar"]
```

find the longest prefix present on at least 2 strings on the list:

```
Longest prefix is "footba" present in "football" and "footbag"
```

The list will be filled through inputs, and not all of them will have a common prefix.

To be considered an option, it's enough that the prefix is present on two strings in the list. If there are multiple options, it has to return the longest one.

In my research I've been able to find how to get the longest common prefix on all strings, for example:

List: `["foo_a","foo_b","foo_c","fnord"]`

Output: `Longest common prefix is "f"`

However, strings on my list might not even start with the same letter.

Comment: Show the code you have. That makes this question more specific and more answerable.

Comment: My code would be the function where I take the inputs to fill the list, which I believe wouldn't be very relevant as I included an example list instead. I don't have any code to solve the problem yet, however I'm actually working on something given the answers I got. I will update as soon as possible

Comment: You can use a `sliding window` to  build `prefix tries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a messy implementation, and won't be efficient for large lists, but it gets the job done. I'd suggest looking into the prefix tries that were mentioned though if you have a bit of time, they'll work a lot better.

This works from the full size word backwards, until two words share the same prefix. It truncates the end of the words and counts how many times the same word appears, and if it's at least 2 it returns it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_to_text(x):
    x = list(map(str, x))
    first = '", "'.join(x[:-1]) #Join together (a, b, c)
    if first:
        return '" and "'.join((first, x[-1])) #Add the last element (a, b, c and d)
    return x[0] #Return a single value if list length is 1

def find_longest_prefix(x):
    x_max = len(max(x, key=len))
    for i in range(1, x_max)[::-1]:

        #Chop off the end of every word
        trim = [j[:i] for j in x]

        #Iterate through every unique value
        result = defaultdict(list)
        for j in set(trim):
            result[trim.count(j)].append(j)

        #Finish iterating if there are more than 2 words that share a prefix
        highest_count = max(result)
        if highest_count >= 2:
            prefix = result[highest_count]
            words = [j for k in prefix for j in x if j.startswith(k)]
            return prefix, words

myList = ["foo", "foobar", "football", "footbag", "bar"]
prefix, words = find_longest_prefix(myList)

#Put together the string
print('The longest common prefix{} "{}" present in "{}".'.format(' is' if len(prefix) ==1 else 'es are',
                                                                 list_to_text(prefix), list_to_text(words)))
```

It will format the string a little based on the number of results. Your list will still result in this:

```
The longest common prefix is "footba" present in "football" and "footbag".
```

But adding another prefix with the same length and number of results will result in something like this:

```
The longest common prefixes are "footba" and "testin" present in "football", "footbag", "testing" and "testin".
```

Comment: Impressive. I'm still realising how the whole code works exactly, as i'm seeing some commands I hadn't seen before, but I want to research some of them before I ask something.
I had to add the parentheses to the print function to make it work, however I already suggested the edit on your answer.

Comment: Ah I guess you're on Python 3 then haha. If you have trouble understanding how some of the lines work I'd be happy to explain, though I'm gonna guess it's the slicing and `key=len` parts. I'd say it's vital to learn how slicing works (and list comprehension if you've not covered that), the other parts you can usually find quite easily through google :)

Comment: Yes haha (I had included the Python version I use on my question but it got edited ¬¬). Also, I got my question flagged as "too broad". Honestly I don't know why since I included an example and the desired output.

Comment: I do understand the key=len. Might check a little about slicing. However, I'm still wondering here: `count = {trim.count(j): j for j in set(trim)}`. At `trim.count(j)` am I using a function there? I guess I got a little confused, since usually we use functions calling them by their "name" and the variable we want to apply it inside the parentheses. However, we were using *trim* and *count* as variables before, do I explain myself?

Comment: The `trim.count(j)` part counts how many times the value appears in the list (and is entirely separate to the `count` variable I set, sorry lol), and if it appears twice then there's your prefix. I have however just realised it only supports a single result, so I'll fix it up shortly :)

Comment: I understand now, and no worries! Just that I got kinda confused with it, because variables name, lol. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Alright gave it a quick update, was doing that between overwatch matches haha

Comment: Thanks a lot man, comments made it way clearer to me. But also, seems like something quite simple but I don't understand, how does this line work?`prefix, words = find_longest_prefix(myList)`... Are we assigning values to both ***prefix*** and ***words*** variables? Or what does the comma do?

Comment: The function returns a tuple of values, so instead of reading `prefix = result[0]` and `words = result[1]`, you can combine them if you know the exact length

Comment: Sweet, I do understand now. Thanks a lot man. I wish I could accept both answers, because both are brilliant, I don't know which one should I accept :(

Comment: Haha, np, and I guess just vote for whichever one you learned a bit more from or end up using :)

Answer (score 2):

You can build a forest of [prefix trie](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-prefix-set-5-using-trie/)s and then search of "height" (how far is it from the root) of the deepest node with two (non-null) children. This node represents the longest common prefix.

If you don't care about performance, you can simply iterate all the words in the list and compare each one of them (its prefix) to the rest while keeping updating the max:

```
def common_prefix_size(s1, s2):
    res, i = 0, 0
    while i < min(len(s1), len(s2)):
        if s1[i] == s2[i]:
            res += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    return res



def longest_prefix(lst):
    res = ''
    maxsize = 0
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            t = common_prefix_size(lst[i], lst[j])
            maxsize = max(maxsize, t)
            if maxsize == t:
                res = lst[i][:maxsize]
    return res

myList = ["foo", "foobar", "football", "footbag", "bar"]

print(longest_prefix(myList)) # footba
```

Comment: I'll definitely take a look into this. Seems a little bit more complex than I expected from the assignment according to what we've seen in class. But I believe that I can manage to understand how to do it and I'd benefit from it. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @oScarDiAnno if you're looking for a less sophisticated solution you can "brute force" your way out of it with simple nested two for-loops (which compares each item to all the rest and updates the max). I'll update the answer

Comment: I was trying to do something like this! I knew there was a way to do it with "knowledge I already have", and I had kinda the same idea but had trouble making it work correctly. I see what you did and this is easier to understand to me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I do understand why the program works, but could you please tell me what the variable names **`res`** and **`t`**  stand for? Just been wondering, maybe it should be something I could infer from common knowledge but maybe it's because English isn't my native language. Thanks again @alfasin

Comment: Also, sorry for this, but I just tried to run it and it doesn't compile, getting this: `NameError: name 'maxsize' is not defined`. I'm not quite sure which value should we assign to maxsize

Comment: @oScarDiAnno my bad: `maxsize` is the size of the max-prefix, `res` contains the max-prefix (code corrected). Each iteration we check the `common_prefix_size()` of two strings and save it into `t` (temp). If `t > maxsize` we update `maxsize` and save the prefix into `res`

Comment: Awesome. Totally understood now. Thanks again! :)